# IF(Contains) in Apex class

Tags: apex

```
 if(temp[i].Items__c.contains(addvalue[i].payment__c)){

    //Some code here
}
```

if temp.items__c size is 2 &  addvalue[i].payment__c size is 1, then getting this error

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 1

Apart from that it works fine.How should I get rid of this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to arrays starting on index 0,

for example if you take your array `addvalue[]`, and you add 3 items A, B and C, say you wanted to get the first value (A) you would have to do `addvalue[0]`, either let your loop start from 0, or have it do `addvalue[i-1]`

if not, I would suggest debugging your arrays and see if all the expected values are correctly filled in.

Comment: here my problem is for the first time it becomes true and when it enters for second time it is showing the error.Went with i-1 but getting the error List index out of bounds: -1

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure there are n=temp.size() items in addvallue ?

It may make more sense to store payment__C objects in map and verify if this map contains an item by key of your temp[i].ID

Comment: Got it.... 

    `for(integer i =0; i<temp.size();i++){ 
       if(temp[i].Items__c.contains(addvalue[i].payment__c)){}
    }`

...
Here I'm iterating only the temp size.Need to iterate the addvalue size also...something like this
  

   `for(integer i =0; i<temp.size();i++){
     for(integer j =0; j<addvalue.size();j++){
       if(temp[i].Items__c.contains(addvalue[j].payment__c)){}
      }

}`

Comment: are you sure there are the same amount of items in temp and addvalue? that will most likely be your problem!

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, but update your question with it. This makes it more readable, and easier to find (it is relevant!) for other readers.  I think it may help if you explain what you want to achieve, versus how you have tried to implement it. So  someone can advise on the better approach to code it.